# How to fix "Too many keys specified; max 1 keys allowed" error?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to alter the engine of a MySQL table from "innodb" to "archive". I've faced with the following error:

[image]

I've looked for it in stackoverflow with no success (I didn't find any usable answer). Any idea how can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the AUTO_INCREMENT to a specific value in the ARCHIVE engine. So just take out the `auto_increment = 379` clause.

The ARCHIVE engine doesn't support more than one index per table. You have to DROP INDEX for all your secondary indexes, leaving at most one index.

In fact, I have not had luck with using even one index in the ARCHIVE engine. I haven't used the ARCHIVE engine often enough to know how to solve this.

```
mysql> alter table t add key (x);
ERROR 1030 (HY000): Got error -1 from storage engine
```

It's a bit hard to find it in the documentation, but I did find references that show that the ARCHIVE storage engine does not support indexes at all, even though the error you got suggests it supports 1 index.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-engines.html says:

> Archive: These compact, **unindexed** tables...

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/archive-storage-engine.html says:

> The ARCHIVE storage engine produces special-purpose tables that store large amounts of **unindexed** data in a very small footprint.
>
> The AUTO_INCREMENT column can have either a unique or nonunique index. Attempting to create an index on any other column results in an error.

Demo:

```
mysql> create table t ( x int auto_increment, key(x)) engine=archive;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)
```

It also doesn't work if you try to index a column that is nullable.

```
mysql> create table t ( x int, key(x)) engine=archive;
ERROR 1121 (42000): Table handler doesn't support NULL in given index. Please change column 'x' to be NOT NULL or use another handler
```

You should consider why you are using the ARCHIVE engine. If you're trying to store data in less space, could you use InnoDB with `ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED` instead?

Comment: [The error has been changed somewhat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1ljN.png)

Comment: It still says "Too many keys specified; max 1 keys allowed" which I addressed in my answer.